# Shared Template

Tags: templating

I have the same embed in 2 sections of a site (homepage and blog). There is a slight html/css change but the data is the same.

Is there any way to do a shared partial template?

Would I be using a block? Should I look into using setting a global var?

This is similar to what I was thinking:

```
{% if page == "homepage" %}
    {% for promo in craft.entries.section('promos').status('live').limit(5) %}
        <div id="promos">
            <div class="promo_item">
                <a href="">
                    <div class="promo_item_img">
                        {% for image in promo.promoImage %}
                            <img src="{{ image.url }}" width="222" height="101">
                        {% endfor %}
                    </div>
                </a>
                <a href="{promolink}"><h2 class="generic_title">| {{ promo.title }}</h2></a>
                <p>{{ promo.promoTagline }}</p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                {% endfor %}
            {% endif %}

            {% if page == "blog" %}
                {% for promo in craft.entries.section('promos').status('live').limit(5) %}
                    <div class="blog_item_inner blog_item_preorder">
                        <a href="">
                            <div class="blog_item_preorder_img">
                                {% for image in promo.promoImage %}
                                    <img src="{{ image.url }}" width="222" height="101">
                                {% endfor %}
                            </div>
                        </a>
                        <a href=""><h2 class="generic_title">| {{ promo.title }}</h2></a>
                        <p>{{ promo.promoTagline }}</p>
                    </div>
                {% endfor %}
            {% endif %}
```

Just want to get the best solution in place early.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, create a sub folder in `/templates` called `_partials`. The underscore essentially "hides" the templates inside that folder from Craft, i.e. they won't get routed to URLs like a regular template; perfect for any template that isn't going to work on its own.

Inside `_partials`, create a template called `_promos.html` or the like. Your Twig code above would work as-is, though I'm making some opinionated improvements below (like setting the `promos` in one place, checking if we actually have some promos to print, and using the [`switch`](http://buildwithcraft.com/docs/templating/switch) tag instead of `if` for readability:

```
{% set promos = craft.entries.section('promos').status('live').limit(5) %}
{% if page is defined and promos|length %}
    {% for promo in promos %}
    {% switch page %}

        {% case "homepage" %}
         <div class="promo_item">
             <a href="">
                <div class="promo_item_img">
                {% for image in promo.promoImage %}
                    <img src="{{ image.url }}" width="222" height="101">
                {% endfor %}
                </div>
            </a>
            <a href="{promolink}"><h2 class="generic_title">| {{ promo.title }}</h2></a>
            <p>{{ promo.promoTagline }}</p>
        </div>

        {% case "blog" %}
        <div class="blog_item_inner blog_item_preorder">
            <a href="">
                <div class="blog_item_preorder_img">
                {% for image in promo.promoImage %}
                    <img src="{{ image.url }}" width="222" height="101">
                {% endfor %}
                </div>
            </a>
            <a href=""><h2 class="generic_title">| {{ promo.title }}</h2></a>
            <p>{{ promo.promoTagline }}</p>
        </div>
    {% endswitch %}
    {% endfor %}
{% endif %}
```

Finally, use the [`include`](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/tags/include.html) tag to include the partial in another template. Use the `with` parameter to set the `page` variable, and the `only` directive to make sure the partial can't access any of the data in the parent template (like the `entry` variable etc). This helps prevent data pollution and variable name collisions (if you need access to the `entry` variable, you can include it in the `with` object).

```
<div id="promos">
    {% include '_partials/promos' with { page : "homepage" } only %}
</div>
```

For the blog, replace the `page` property with "blog".

Finally, as far as I can tell, the only difference between the two blocks of Twig are different classes for the containers (`blog_item` vs. `promo_item` etc). If possible, I'd consider refactoring your code to use the same classnames both "blog" and "homepage" – this would make your code more lean and [DRY](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself), and probably easier to maintain.

If you can't change the classnames, you could also make them dynamic and expose them to the `include` statement like this:

```
{% include '_partials/promos' with { page : "blog", classNames : {
    'item' : 'blog_item_inner blog_item_preorder',
    'image' : 'blog_item_preorder_img'
} } only %}
```

...and then print those classnames inside the partial (which now won't require the `switch` tag or duplicated markup:

```
{% set promos = craft.entries.section('promos').status('live').limit(5) %}
{% if classNames is defined and promos|length %}
    {% for promo in promos %}
         <div class="{{ classNames.item }}">
             <a href="">
                <div class="{{ classNames.image }}">
                {% for image in promo.promoImage %}
                    <img src="{{ image.url }}" width="222" height="101">
                {% endfor %}
                </div>
            </a>
            <a href="{promolink}"><h2 class="generic_title">| {{ promo.title }}</h2></a>
            <p>{{ promo.promoTagline }}</p>
        </div>
    {% endfor %}
{% endif %}
```

Comment: I'm going to buy you lots of beers one day, @mmikkel.

Comment: Lol, I sincerely hope you get the chance to one day, @BradBell ;)